# R Extending each list level by new elements

Tags: r, list, purrr

I'm looking for a way to automatically add new list elements/levels to an existing list:

- my real-life use case has several thousand elements to add, so the manual example below for adding two elements is not feasible anymore,
- I need a list because that's the format expected by an API I'm trying to access.

**Example:**

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- data.frame(id    = c(1,2,3),
                label = c("label 1", "label 2", "label 3"),
                category = c("cat 1", "cat 2", "cat 3"))

x_list <- x %>%
  as.list() %>%
  transpose()

names <- c("name 1", "name 2")

# Expected final format/output    
full_list <- list(list(name = names[1],
                       info = x_list),
                  list(name = names[2],
                       info = x_list))
```

So I'm looking for a way to create this list of lists, where I "glue together" all values from the `names` vector with a "copy" ot the `x_list`.

I'm not that familiar with lists, so struggling quite a bit. I know that the `purrr` package can do awesome list things, so I'm open/looking forward to a tidyverse approach, although I'm also gladly taking base R. Thanks.

Comment: It is highly recommended to not create variables that have the same symbol as base R functions (ie `names()`).

Comment: true, was just for illustrative purposes and I didn't put too much effort in keeping all conventions in mind.

Comment: Just a thought to keep in mind is that people that want to help you are going to be inputing your example data. If they forget to remove it afterwards, then trouble might ensue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over names using map or using the same arguments replace map with lapply in which case no packages are needed.

```
library(purrr)
result <- map(names, function(nm) list(name = nm, info = x_list))

identical(result, full_list)
## [1] TRUE
```